# Magento 1.9 : Xdebug can no longer be used for as xdebug no longer support php 5

Tags: magento-1.9, xdebug

I am trying to use Xdebug for magento 1. However, Xdebug no longer supports PHP under 7.0. Magento 1 on the other hand only works for php 5.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem. [image]

Comment: just install an older version ..

Comment: yes. good point. but where to find an older version? there site does not have an older version

Comment: yes. but where do i get the old version from . its not on their site

Comment: Do note that PHP 5.6 will reach EoL at the end of this year. To stay PCI compliant, you'll need PHP 7.2. I recommend developing against 7.2 to stay ahead of this curve (unless you are 100% sure that the bug you're debugging is specific to PHP 5.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download older versions of xdebug which are compatible with php 5.

You can see and download all the versions released till now here - https://xdebug.org/download.php

Just scroll down and look for a compatible version to your corresponding php.

Comment: my bad. i did not see it. thanks mate

Comment: Np, Glad I could help!